# Javascript - Alternatives to setTimeout, clearTimeout, setInterval, clearInterval

Tags: javascript, concurrency

I am looking at alternative ways to solve concurrent problems using javascript. One such issue that I am trying to solve is the consumption and processing of a large catalog for a mobile application. I am currently trying to implement a catalog application that contains a large amount of items on many categories... I am having a hard time coping with the challenge.

I have looked at webworkers but this is a mobile application that has to run on browsers that do not support such browser features.

What would be the most appropriate approach to tackle such a challenge. Any previous experiences would be hugely beneficial.

Comment: I'd do it on the server side; a lot of mobile devices don't have the processing power available to go through a lot of data.

Comment: The data is processed server side but still has to work off-line, and that is the very tricky part. It has to retain part of the catalog and still be able to process orders. The catalog is provided via web service.

Comment: If you exclude webworkers, there is no way to run on more than one thread in javascript.

Comment: Indeed that is why I am trying to find techniques that will allow me to work around this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at IcedCoffeeScript: http://maxtaco.github.com/coffee-script/

Comment: thanks. Ill take a look at it, though I am a bit biased against adding yet another layer.